# Triggering custom action only on uninstall

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a custom action that is removing from database related to the product records from different tables. Right now it is set like this:

```
<Custom Action="caUnregisterServer" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed</Custom>
```

Then, I modified a product features from Programs and Features menu, by clicking on Change button and  noticed that custom action caUnregisterServer executed! How can I run this action on uninstall only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer to your question is the condition, REMOVE~="ALL"

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537584/how-to-execute-custom-action-only-in-install-not-uninstall) the link.