# Wix IniFile addTag also adds the tag during a patch, resulting in multiple ini file entries

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have an installer for a Lotus Notes extension.  I need to add entries to the `notes.ini` file so that it will call my extension.  I'm using the `<IniFile addTag>` as follows:

```
    <Directory Id="LOTUSNOTESINSTALLDIRECTORY">
        <Component Id="NOTESINIADDINMENUS" Guid="{FC239067-1B5D-48b4-AA9A-8B89F62F21E7}" KeyPath="yes" Win64="no">
          <IniFile Id="HLBridgeDLLINI" Action="addTag" Directory="LOTUSNOTESINIDIRECTORY" Name="Notes.ini" Section="Notes" Key="AddInMenus" Value="HLBridge.dll"/>
        </Component>
    ...
```

This does exactly what I want on initial install.  However, when I apply an MSP patch, the entry gets written again, resulting in a double entry for HLBridge.dll.

I have tried using a condition such as `"&Feature=3 AND !Feature=2"` to only do the `addTag` if the feature is first being installed, but apparently in Wix the feature values are not available at this point.  (I can't find the stackoverflow answer that told me why it wasn't working.)

Perhaps `addLine` would not have this problem, but would disable other installed Notes extensions.

Is there a way to handle this without writing a custom action?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an additional component where you add the `IniFile`-tag and an additional [`Condition`-tag](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html), so this component and therefore also the related `IniFile`-modification is only executed if the condition is met.
For the condition itself you can take also a look at e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538876/1785391) where the `PATCH`-property is also used in the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Using `<Condition><![CDATA[NOT Installed AND NOT Patch]]></Condition>` solves this problem.  Unfortunately, I've also discovered that a repair install has this problem too.  There doesn't appear to be a REPAIR variable and I haven't worked out the expression to exclude repair as well.

Comment: @jsparkes See this [article](http://code.dblock.org/msi-property-patterns-upgrading-firstinstall-and-maintenance) on detecting scenarios. Also the comment to the article regarding the updated WiX upgrade element.